# Why do I encounter "There is a problem parsing the package" and how to avoid it

Tags: installation

I always face this problem during installation of app on my Huawei phone. Anybody got help?

Comment: Those apps might not be supported for your Android version.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities:

1. Your APK is corrupted (most common for me)

   - Get another copy (i.e. Download it again)
2. Your APK file is incompatible

   - Check if your phone can meet the app's requirements.